# Problems with Hangman in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to find out what is wrong with the folowing code:

```
import pygame, sys, random, linecache
from pygame.locals import *

#Start Pygame, define Pygame objects
pygame.init()
hangmanSurfaceObj = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480), 0)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Define colors
redColor = pygame.Color(255,0,0)
greenColor = pygame.Color(0,255,0)
blueColor = pygame.Color(0,0,255)
whiteColor = pygame.Color(255,255,255)
blackColor = pygame.Color(0,0,0)
tardisBlueColor = pygame.Color(16,35,114)
bgColor = whiteColor

#Import Images
hangmanImage = pygame.image.load('hangmanResources/hangman.png')

#Import sounds
sadTromboneSound = pygame.mixer.music.load('hangmanResources/sadTrombone.mp3')

#Import Font
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('hangmanResources/Avenir_95_Black.ttf', 18)

#Define global variables
currentWord = 0
usrWord = ''
screenWord = []
i = 0
currentChar = ''
guesses = 0

def terminate():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

def drawRects(tries):

    if tries<=0:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(242,65,65,65))
    if tries<=1:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(257,90,35,4))
    if tries<=2:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(261,110,27,1))
    if tries<=3:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(274,130,1,114))
    if tries<=4:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(198,160,76,1))
    if tries<=5:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(275,160,75,1))
    if tries<=6:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(210,244,64,85))
    if tries<=7:
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor, pygame.Rect(274,244,51,87))


def newGame(players):
    if players == 1:
        line_number = random.randint(0, 2283)
        usrWord = linecache.getline('hangmanResources/words.txt', line_number)
        usrWord = list(usrWord)
        del usrWord[-1]
        print(usrWord)
        screenWord = ['_']*len(usrWord)
        print(screenWord)

def checkChar(usrWord):
    print('hi')
    i=0
    addGuess = 1
    print(len(usrWord))
    while i <= (len(usrWord)-1):
        print('hi2')
        if currentChar.lower == usrWord[i]:
            print('hi3')
            screenWord[i] = currentChar
            addGuess = 0

    return addGuess


newGame(1)

while True:
    gameRunning = 1
    while gameRunning==1:


        for event in pygame.event.get(QUIT):
            terminate()

        for event in pygame.event.get(KEYDOWN):
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()
            else:
                currentChar = event.unicode
                guesses +=checkChar(usrWord)
                print(currentChar)
                print(screenWord)
                msg = ''.join(screenWord)

                msgSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(msg, False, blackColor)
                msgRectObj = msgSurfaceObj.get_rect()
                msgRectObj.topleft = (10, 20)
                hangmanSurfaceObj.blit(msgSurfaceObj, msgRectObj)


        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor)
        hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(blueColor, pygame.Rect(400,0,640,480))

        hangmanSurfaceObj.blit(hangmanImage, (0,0))

        if guesses<=7:
            drawRects(guesses)

        else:
            won=0
            gameRunning = 0


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

    newGame(1)
```

It is supposed to be a hangman game with a hanging post showing, letter blanks showing, and a blue rectangle on the right (where game controls will eventually go).

When I go to run it the hanging post appears, the blue rectangle on the left appears, and although no errors pop up, the letter blanks don't show up, and there is a strange blue box connected to the corner of the blue rectangle.  More importantly, though, the problem that I'm having is that once you enter a character, the string which holds the data for the eventual on-screen output doesn't change.  For instance, if the guess word is "Turtle" and I enter "t", then it should change from `['_','_','_','_','_','_']` to `['t','_','_','t','_','_']`, but it doesn't.

I used Python 3.1.3 and Pygame 1.9.1.

I searched the Python as well as Pygame documentations for the functions that I am using, but unfortunately I could find no recourse.

The original file, as well as the resources, can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hangman4pygame/files/).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry but in that code there isn't any code for drawing the letter blanks nor the the real letters and there isn't even a guess frase defined.

Comment: I can't find any code that would draw the letters in here. Is this all the code? All I see is the code for drawing the hangee, drawing the different rects depending on how many guesses, changing the current colour (which isnt even used) and filling the screen with white.

Comment: OMG!  I'm so sorry!  I copied the wrong version of the file!  I will update the code in the question.  This new version has no code to render the guess phrase on-screen (@pmoleri, @hammythepig), but it will print it to the Shell.

Comment: Your link is still missing assets. You can throw the directory into a folder, and share it on dropbox. Then it updates when you update the code.

Comment: @monkey sorry!  I included the wrong link!  I fixed it in the question, but just in case that doesn't work I'll put it [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hangman4pygame/files/) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are blitting the phrase only during keydown then in every frame you clean the screen. At 30 fps you are lucky if you see a blink of the phrase.
You should check the frase at key down but blit the frase on every frame.

```
     ...
     for event in pygame.event.get(KEYDOWN):
        if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
            terminate()
        else:
            currentChar = event.unicode
            guesses +=checkChar(usrWord)
            print(currentChar)
            print(screenWord)
            msg = ''.join(screenWord)

    # Clean background
    hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(bgColor)

    # Then blit message
    msgSurfaceObj = fontObj.render(msg, False, blackColor)
    msgRectObj = msgSurfaceObj.get_rect()
    msgRectObj.topleft = (10, 20)
    hangmanSurfaceObj.blit(msgSurfaceObj, msgRectObj)

    ...
```

**Edit**

About the blue rectangle attached to the control box, it's because you are making the control box 200px wide and then overwriting the first 100px with your drawRects() rountine.

You can either make the control box 100px wide:

```
hangmanSurfaceObj.fill(blueColor, pygame.Rect(400,0,640,480))
```

or modify drawRects() routine so the rects don't overlap the control box.

Comment: WOW I see my problem now. Thanks. I don't have access to a computer right now but as soon as I do I'll try it out.  As for the strange extra blue square, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add you to comment yesterday